# Getting no auth provider for github error in backstage

Tags: github, backstage

I have created a new component in backstage and iam trying to add github actions to that component.

But when I try to login to github , it is giving me this error

```
{
   "error":{
      "name":"NotFoundError",
      "message":"No auth provider registered for 'github'",
      "stack":"NotFoundError: No auth provider registered for 'github'\n    at /workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/@backstage/plugin-auth-backend/dist/index.cjs.js:3541:15\n    at handleReturn (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:24:23)\n    at /workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:64:7\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)\n    at /workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9\n    at Function.process_params (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)\n    at next (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)\n    at jsonParser (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:110:7)\n    at handleReturn (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:24:23)\n    at jsonParser (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:64:7)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)\n    at /workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9\n    at Function.process_params (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)\n    at next (/workspace/backstagePOC/backstage-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)"
   },
   "request":{
      "method":"GET",
      "url":"/api/auth/github/start?scope=read%3Auser%20repo&origin=https%3A%2F%2F3000-rapidxdevel-backstagepo-qgnhs2lefe6.ws-us93.gitpod.io&env=development"
   },
   "response":{
      "statusCode":404
   }
}
```

I have created a Oauth github app and added the client ID and secret in app-config.yaml file also

```
auth:
  environment: development
  providers:
    github:
    development:
      clientId: 83b5c305091c
      clientSecret: a7b2de36eb42e076eec448
```

How to solve this auth provider error?

Comment: from my understanding ,the plugins typically use the tokens provided in the integrations section of the app-config (Github App or Personal Access Token )

Answer (score 0):

Have you validated your authentication system in the "local environment"?

The [Backstage documentation](https://backstage.io/docs/auth/github/provider#create-an-oauth-app-on-github) itself recommends this configuration:

```
- Application name: Backstage (or your custom app name)
- Homepage URL: http://localhost:3000
- Authorization callback URL: http://localhost:7007/api/auth/github/handler/frame
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works with following code snipped in yaml config

```
auth:
  allowGuestAccess: true
  environment: development
  providers:
    github:
      development:
        clientId: xxxxx
        clientSecret: xxxxxxx
```

and **Github OAuth Apps** with **Homepage URL**  and **Authorization callback URL** with **/api/auth/github/handler/frame** at the end for "**Homepage URL**".

Answer (score 0):

```
auth:
  allowGuestAccess: true
  environment: development
  providers:
    github:
      development:
        clientId: xxxxx
        clientSecret: xxxxxxx
```

Put this part of code above `backend` configuration and it worked for me.
PS:
Make sure other steps followed correctly.